# Pyspark -Filtering the rows based on language

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

This issue is related to Pyspark. I'm reading a TSV file which have few columns. The one specific columns is comment column. My task is to filter out the rows based on the language. For example, if the comment is in Russian language than I want to filter that particular row and save it in a separate file.

Now while reading the file I am using below code which is making Dataframes.

```
Info = sqlContext.read.format("csv"). \
option("delimiter","\t"). \
option("header", "True"). \
option("inferSchema", "True"). \
load("file.tsv")

DataFrame[ID: int Comments: string]
```

Then I am trying to use ORD function to filter out the record based on the ASCII values:

```
Info.filter((map(ord,Info.Comments)) < 128).collect()
```

However, I'm getting an error:

> TypeError: argument 2 to map() must support iteration

Sample Input :

```
Comments

{175:'Аксессуары'}
{156:'Горные'}
{45:'Кровати, диваны и кресла'}
{45:'Кровати, диваны и кресла'}
```

Please suggest some solution. Any help/suggestion is appreciated.

Updated:

@ags29

I have rectified  the error that i mentioned in comments by writing this code.

```
spark_ord=F.udf(lambda x: [ord(c) for c in x],t.ArrayType(IntegerType()))
Info=Info.withColumn('russ', spark_ord('Comments'))

DataFrame[ID: int, Comments: string, russ: array<int>]
```

Now the issue is as it is creating the Array[Int]. I have to filter the whole row based on the value present in the Array which should be less than 128.

I am struggling to achieve that. Please suggest.

Comment: Did my answer below help you? Let me know if you have any questions

Comment: I am getting below error while i am trying to run this command. I guess UDF s not created properly. 

Info=Info.withColumn('ord', spark_ord('Comments')).show() 

TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but NoneType found

Comment: I would suggest first checking the inputs (i.e. check there are no nulls). Remove any nulls and test again. If it works then we just need error handling in the udf. Let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ags29 Thanks for your suggestion.

**Here is the Answer :**

After creating the Dataframe by reading the file as mentioned above, we have to replace Null values with some value, in this case I am replacing it with NA.

```
InfoWoNull = Info.fillna({'Comments':'NA'})
```

Then, Create UDF to find ASCII value for each character in the string using ORD function. Output will be array of integer.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import types as t
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, IntegerType

russ_ord=F.udf(lambda x: [ord(a) for a in x],t.ArrayType(IntegerType()))
```

Create Filter function to filter out the value based on ASCII character greater than 127.

```
def russian_filter(x):
for index in range(len(x)):
    if x[index] > 127:
    return True
return False

filter_udf = F.udf(russian_filter, BooleanType())
```

Use it in the final step like below.

```
Info_rus = InfoWoNull.filter(filter_udf(russ_ord('SearchParams')) == 'true')
Info_rus.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not tested, but something along these lines should work:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType

# create user defined function from ord
spark_ord=udf(lambda x: ord(x), IntegerType())

Info=Info.withColumn('ord', spark_ord('Comments'))
Info=Info.filter('ord<128')
```

Basically, to use the `ord` function with a DataFrame, you need a user defined function. The method you tried would require an RDD, not a DataFrame

Comment: I am getting below error while i am trying to run this command. I guess UDF s not created properly.

Info=Info.withColumn('ord', spark_ord('Comments')).show()

     TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but NoneType found